# The person who is the making the complaint or compliment

Tags: single-word-requests

I am creating a document to list "Complaints and Compliments" by customers/suppliers/staff/anyone, I want a column heading preferably a single word do describe the person making the compliment or complaint. The column will contain their name.

Comment: Does "customer" not meet your needs?

Comment: I should have expanded that it could be anyone. I have edited the post.

Comment: Complainer? (and then the person being complained about it complainee)

Comment: @Smock But what if the person made a compliment?

Comment: oh I see - so one word to cover whether they complain OR compliment. Commenter ? Ugh..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **originator**. From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/originator):

> countable noun [usu with poss]
>
> The originator of something such as an idea or scheme is the person who first thought of it or began it.
>   
>   *[formal]
>
>   ...the originator of the theory of relativity.*